# Saving arrays with XamlWriter

Tags: c#, arrays, xaml, xamlwriter

I am trying to save a collection of objects with `XamlWriter` in the simplest way possible. For some reason saving them as an array produces invalid XML:

```
var array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
Console.Write(XamlWriter.Save(array));
```

outputs:

```
<Int32[] xmlns="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
   <Int32>1</Int32>
   <Int32>2</Int32>
   <Int32>3</Int32>
</Int32[]>
```

Attempting to read this using `XamlReader` throws:

> The '[' character, hexadecimal value 0x5B, cannot be included in a
>   name. Line 1, position 7

I've tried saving as a `List<T>` instead but I get the usual XAML generics error. Is there some simple way I can do it (preferably with LINQ) or do I have to define my own wrapper type?

Comment: Why are you trying to save it with the `XamlWriter`?

Comment: Because I'm not really saving ints, I'm saving WPF controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`XamlWriter.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590450.aspx) produces invalid XML.

```
<Int32[] xmlns="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
   <Int32>1</Int32>
   <Int32>2</Int32>
   <Int32>3</Int32>
</Int32[]>
```

I don't know the reasons behind that, but using [`XamlServices.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd273578.aspx) seems to fix the problem.

```
<x:Array Type="x:Int32" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
  <x:Int32>2</x:Int32>
  <x:Int32>3</x:Int32>
</x:Array>
```

---

Additional notes from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834866.aspx)

> The following classes exist in both the WPF assemblies and the
>   `System.Xaml` assembly in the .NET Framework 4:
>
> - `XamlReader`
> - `XamlWriter`
> - `XamlParseException`
>
> The WPF implementation is found in the `System.Windows.Markup` namespace, and `PresentationFramework` assembly.
>
> The `System.Xaml` implementation is found in the `System.Xaml`
>   namespace.
>
> If you are using WPF types or are deriving from WPF types, you should
>   typically use the WPF implementations of
>   [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx)
>   and
>   [`XamlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx)
>   instead of the `System.Xaml` implementations.
>
> For more information, see Remarks in
>   [`System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx)
>   and
>   [`System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What about using `UIElementCollection` instead of an array? `UIElementCollection` serializes nicely:

```
var buttonArray = new Button[] { new Button(), new Button() };
var root = new FrameworkElement();
var collection = new UIElementCollection(root, root);

foreach(var button in buttonArray)
    collection.Add(button);

Console.Write(XamlWriter.Save(collection));
```

Gives you:

```
<UIElementCollection Capacity="2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Button />
    <Button />
</UIElementCollection>
```